# Redundant U-Boot images

Tags: boot-loader, u-boot

I'm currently working on an embedded system which uses a NAND flash as it main storage. Bootloader + Kernel + rootfs are written to it, and we are looking for ways to make our system more robust to the many issues related to NAND.

Currently, we have the kernel and rootfs partitions on top of JFFS2, and we are trying to find a way to safeguard out bootloader partititions (we are using SPL plus U-Boot).

Our processor is capable of looking into the first 4 blocks of flash automatically for an uncorrupted SPL image, and I would like to have something similar for U-Boot. However, I checked through the U-Boot code, and did not find any way to enable such a feature.

Is this even supported by U-Boot? I tried hacking my own code to do this, but no luck so far.

**tl;dr**: *I want to be able to detect if I have a bad U-Boot image on NAND, and if so, boot from another (hopefully) uncorrupted partition.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I managed to implement a simple check and boot from a redundant image. All you have to do is catch the return code from a call to `ecc.correct()` and treat it in the `spl_nand_load_image()` function. I posted a patch [here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/linux/f/354/t/505682).

Answer (score 1):

Normally the U-Boot SPL does ECC, but doesn't update NAND...but I believe that's something you already know.
**A good practice is to store U-Boot in NOR, and the kernel, FS and the redundant U-Boot environment variables in NAND.**  
Now regarding the kernel: the legacy linux kernel image (uImage) has a weak CRC32 checksum, I would opt for fitImage which can be signed and contains a configurable checksum algorithm among other useful things.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've seen the redundant environment setting, but it is not very useful for our application, as the environment won't be updated once we finish development.

I've checked on the ECC capabilities of U-Boot, but we are also looking for a redundant solution due to bad blocks on the U-Boot partition. I've messed around with the code a bit, and I believe I managed to implement this 'image switch' will perform a few more tests, and post the results =]